# Python Selenium: Unable to use ActionChains to go through two menus before clicking on an element

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I have been trying to click on an element that appears two levels down in a menu that is accessed by hovering over.

Eg. Menu -> Sub-Menu -> Element to be clicked

```
content_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath>")     
sub_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath>")
click_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath>")
action = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(content_menu)
action.move_to_element(sub_menu)
action.click(click_item)
action.perform()
```

This code does not click on the element. If I use the chain to only hover over first menu item, it does, but it does not display the list under it, from where I would choose the second item. Is there something I can do to fix my code, or is there a better solution for this particular case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in *multiple action chains calls*:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.move_to_element(content_menu).perform()
actions.move_to_element(sub_menu).perform()
actions.click(click_item).perform()
```

There also might be a need to [wait until the `sub_menu` and `click_item` would be visible](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: Thank you . Like you said I had to also give time.sleep() to get it to work.